# Scan iTunes Library?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, itunes

I'm working on a Mac app and I need it to scan the users iTunes library. Any idea how I would go about this? The app would scan the library looking for different song attributes.

Comment: Itunes library creates a xml with all song details , try parsing it!

Comment: That should do the trick! Thanks for the help. Do you happen to know of a way I could go about finding that XML file no matter where the user stores their iTunes library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To find the actual most recent location of the iTunes library (and not hope for it to be at the default location) read the `iTunesRecentDatabases` or `iTunesRecentDatabasePaths` property from `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iApps.plist`.

```
NSArray *libraryDatabases = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.iApps"] objectForKey:@"iTunesRecentDatabases"];
NSURL *libraryURL = (([libraryDatabases count])) ? [NSURL URLWithString:[dbs objectAtIndex:0]] : nil;
```

For a more advanced code snippet look for `parserInstancesForMediaType:` in **iMedia**'s [IMBiTunesParser.m](http://imedia.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/IMBiTunesParser.m)

---

For the actual database parsing it is recommended to use a SAX parser, such as `NSXMLParser` (vs. a tree parser, such as `NSXMLDocument` or even worse: `NSPropertylistSerialization`) as some users have librares with up to and sometimes even more than 100,000+ tracks. Using tree parsing or even serialization will seriously slow down and potentially block your app temporarily.

Comment: This is more safer way, Thanks for new knowledge Regexident. +1.

Comment: @krio: If an answer solved your question please click the green checkbox next to the answer to mark your question solved. This makes it easier for others to search for correct solutions on StackOverflow. In the meanwhile, welcome and have a nice stay at StackOverflow! :)

Comment: I wish I could Regexident and I always do when I ask question. But this question is asked by Sam. lol However I up voted you.